# How can I add a Horizontal Scroll Bar in System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, scrollbar

I want to add a Horizontal Scroll Bar in System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox. The data that's need to be shown in the dropdown is very large. So, I can't just increase the Maximum Size. It will exceed the screen and will look bad.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this or is there any workaround for this?

I tried increasing the MaximumSize of the ComboBox but the data was large so, it was exceeding the screen.

[image]

Comment: You can probably call `SetWindowLongPtr()` to set the `WS_HSCROLL` style, then send a `LB_SETHORIZONTALEXTENT` message to set the horizontal extent to the largest string (in pixels). But you then, most probably, have to update the scroll thumb position yourself, otherwise it will remain fixed at the default position. So you need a NativeWindow to handle the messages of the ListBox... (but maybe calling `SetScrollInfo()` is enough)

Comment: Of course you have to retrieve the handle of the List Control of your ComboBox. You can use [GetComboBoxInfo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcomboboxinfo) for that

Comment: As a note, *the data was so large, it was exceeding the screen* shouldn't be a thing. You could add some sort of alias / replacement text to the ComboBox and present the actual  text, in its full extent, in another, multiline, Control